# ClickOnce application won't start

Tags: windows-10, clickonce

Only on this one Win 10 PC it doesn't work, it just won't start, no messages why, not even in the log. I've even disabled firewall and anti-virus. I've even tried copying exe file and starting it without deployment and it worked, so there are no issues with the program. What should I do next?

This is the log:

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 10.0.17134.0 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.42000
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.7.3056.0 built by: NET472REL1
    clr.dll             : 4.7.3110.0 built by: NET472REL1LAST_C
    dfdll.dll           : 4.7.3056.0 built by: NET472REL1
    dfshim.dll          : 10.0.17134.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : file:///C:/Users/Vlatka/Desktop/Sindikat.appref-ms%7C
                        Server      : Microsoft-IIS/10.0
                        X-Powered-By    : ASP.NET
    Deployment Provider url     : http://...

ERROR SUMMARY
    No errors were detected during this operation.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    * The manifest for this application does not have a signature. Signature validation will be ignored.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [25.5.2018. 11:09:29] : Activation of C:\Users\Vlatka\Desktop\Sindikat.appref-ms| has started.
    * [25.5.2018. 11:09:29] : Performing necessary update check as specified by the deployment.
    * [25.5.2018. 11:09:30] : Activation of C:\Users\Vlatka\Desktop\Sindikat.appref-ms| succeeded.

ERROR DETAILS
    No errors were detected during this operation.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

Comment: Try to add http://app.nsdmup-a.hr address in "Trusted sites"

Comment: The filename extension is certainly very unusual, note the %7C in the name.  This needs to be just plain `.appref-ms`.  I'd use a very long pole to touch that machine :)

Comment: I just wanted to add that I experience this problem as well.  I can open my clickonce app several times, but then it will stop opening after some time.  No errors, no response what so ever.  This happens with 2 clickonce apps that I develop.  Only happens in Windows 10.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was new Windows Defender with ClickOnce update before app start, I've just changed that it looks for an update after the app start. Defender didn't warn the user if he would like to allow the app to start, despite the picked Warn option.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to select the "This is a full trust application" option in "Properties > Security" before publish.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're having difficulty starting an app deployed with ClickOnce, check your *Event Viewer* `Application` logs. Chances are some errors are being logged there. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52835712/clickonce-shortcut-doesnt-start-application) is another question which more specifically addressed my problem, the root cause being that I needed to generate an application manifest with full security permissions granted.

Answer (score 0):

stop the task in task scheduler "\Microsoft\Windows\Application Experience\Microsoft Compatibility Appraiser"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

If you're installing on a completely new computer with Windows 10 and .NET Framework 4.8 and it doesn't launch, **you most likely need to install Visual Studio to install any old dependencies you app might need**.

It's definitely not a perfect solution but at least it works.

Comment: I've dropped ClickOnce completely and made my own software update solution with gRPC. I have no problems with users installing my software since.